# Netplan configuration is not persistent

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have configured my network interfaces in my `Ubuntu bionic (18.04)` server using `netplan`, and afterwords I ran `netplan apply` and the configuration kicked in.
In particular, I configured the DNS servers, and my server did resolved ips with the nameservers I configured in my `netplan` configuration.

But, after reboot, the configuration didn't last and any resolving was by default to the `127.0.0.53` nameserver. Only after running `netplan apply` the configuration kicked in again.

How can I make the `netplan` configuration persistent to reboots?

Output of `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

My netplan yaml files:

`10-nameservers.yaml`:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            nameservers:
                addresses: [127.0.0.1]
```

`50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp-identifier: mac
    version: 2
```

`interfaces_ens160.yaml`

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [172.16.0.1/16]
      dhcp4: 'no'
      dhcp6: 'no'
      gateway4: 172.16.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.8, 8.8.8.8, 10.15.0.18]
  version: 2
```

Comment: Is this a server or desktop installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Uploaded :)

Comment: You must have manually created two of the .yaml files, yes? Which ones? Does your ethernet connection need a static address, or is a dynamic address ok? Are you sure the gateway is correct for that static address? Where are DNS servers 10.0.0.8 and 10.15.0.18?

Comment: Yes, I created the `interfaces_ens160.yaml` and `10-nameservers.yaml`... And my system demands an static IP. Both nameservers are needed... After running `netplan apply` this conf works perfectly, but when the server reboots, the conf doesn't seem to be applied... @heynnema

Comment: I'll need to write you a new .yaml file. But first, show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq* and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: status please...

Comment: I'm building the system from scarch, I'll update in a couple of hours... Thank you so much! @heynnema

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that in this ENV, the resolvconf rpm was installed and uninstalled, preserving the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Deleting the file solved the issue.

Comment: If you deleted /etc/resolv.conf, you don't want to do that. It's required. You'll need to recreate the symlink.

Comment: Why it's required for netplan?

Comment: Because software uses that file to track DNS server addresses. It's actually a symlink to one of three possible other files on the system. Deleting this file solved what issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting .yaml files.

**Rename all of the existing .yaml files**

- sudo mv `/etc/netplan/10-nameservers.yaml` `/etc/netplan/10-nameservers.yaml.HOLD`
- sudo mv `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml.HOLD`
- sudo mv `/etc/netplan/interfaces_ens160.yaml` `/etc/netplan/interfaces_ens160.yaml.HOLD`

**Create a new .yaml file**

- sudo pico `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` with the following contents... with exact indentation, spacing, and no tabs...

---

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [172.16.0.1/16]
      gateway4: 172.16.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.8, 8.8.8.8, 10.15.0.18]
```

---

**Generate new files**

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply config

`reboot` # reboot the server

Comment: Not using `netplan` so can't comment on answer but, using `sudo mv /etc/netplan/10-nameservers.yaml /etc/netplan/10-nameservers.yaml.HOLD` in answer rather than human instructions "rename blah to blah" allows them to copy and paste from your answer direct to their terminal :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix edits done. Thanks!

Comment: It does work, but my question is- why is my configuration, no differ then that, but in different files, doesn't work... It generates the same output from the `systemd-resolve --status` and after `netplan apply` the old configuration, so there is seems to be something I forget to apply or something after reboot? @heynnema

Comment: @YuvalPruss  Your 3 .yaml files had conflicting instructions. ex: one had dhcp4 and the other had static addressing.

Answer (score -1):

Ok - I did exactly as advised by @heynnema to configure a static ip and here's what I get after reboot:

neilp@Lubuntu:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

*2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 44:87:fc:5a:92:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

**inet 192.168.0.199/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp3s0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever**

**inet 192.168.0.214/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary enp3s0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever**

```
inet6 2c0f:f5f0:40e0:60:4687:fcff:fe5a:9273/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 2591931sec preferred_lft 604731sec
inet6 fe80::4687:fcff:fe5a:9273/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever*
```

**192.168.0.214**  is the desired static ip address but the **192.168.0.199/24** address is from dhcp and it seems to be because for some reason the system continually regenerates the file **/run/netplan/enp3s0.yaml** with the following contents:

network:

version: 2

renderer: networkd

ethernets:

```
enp3s0:

  dhcp4: true

  dhcp-identifier: mac

  critical: true

  nameservers:

    addresses: ["192.168.0.1"]
```

It does not help to delete this file because it just regenerates after reboot.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question.